# Session variables lost on Callback from another provider

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, worldpay

Our application is on ASP.net MVC 5, .Net Framework 4.6 , we are using Custom SQL session State

```
<sessionState mode="Custom" customProvider="mssql" cookieless="false" timeout="20">
  <providers>
    <add name="mongo" type="Sitecore.SessionProvider.MongoDB.MongoSessionStateProvider, Sitecore.SessionProvider.MongoDB" sessionType="Standard" connectionStringName="session" pollingInterval="2" compression="true" />
    <add name="mssql" type="Sitecore.SessionProvider.Sql.SqlSessionStateProvider, Sitecore.SessionProvider.Sql" sessionType="private" connectionStringName="session" pollingInterval="2" compression="true" />
    <add name="redis" type="Sitecore.SessionProvider.Redis.RedisSessionStateProvider, Sitecore.SessionProvider.Redis" applicationName="Application" connectionString="session" pollingInterval="2" compression="true" />
  </providers>
</sessionState>
```

We are currently working on a Payment Provider Integration(worldpay), we have a 3 step Join process where we collect, personal details, Billing details, Account creation details, each step updates information in a session variable

On Submit, The application calls a Payment provider API by passing the billing details and a callback URL to post Transaction Status, Upon successful transaction, we would create a user on our application with all the details stored in the session

Problem :

On POST back to the Callback Url from the payment provider, my session variable with user details is lost, a new session ID is created

Before Post back, there are 15 Session Variables

[image]

After postback there are 3 session variables

[image]

Any help on how this can be resolved?

Comment: If you go through the process and make the payment request so that it appears like the session has been reset, but then browse to your site normally, does the original session information become visible again?

Comment: Hi Craig ,Thanks for your reply , it shows the new session that gets created on Callback